# blank number field causing fatal exception even if checked

Tags: java, android, textfield

I'm trying to make sure when you forget to enter a number that my app won't crash, I have a text field called 
edit that only accepts numbers, I am getting this error when i test what happens if you don't enter anything in the text field, which is a numeric text field and only brings up the number keyboard on your device, so you cant enter text at all just numbers
can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

this is the error message:
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.***.rhgtimecard, PID: 27379
   java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""
   at com.***.rhgtimecard.TimeIn$2.onClick(TimeIn.java:478)

And this is the related code block

```
if (login == 1) {
    int getemn = 0;
if (!edit.equals("")) {//**if you didn't enter anything but pressed set anyway this should stop the rest of the code block.
    //I tried setting this to if (edit != null) didn't work either, tried setting this to if (!edit.equals()) but it wont 
    //compile like that at all** 
    getemn = Integer.parseInt(edit.getText().toString());//**this is line 478 that throws the fatal exception error**
    String getemp = edit2.getText().toString();
    String allpass = "Passwords";
    SharedPreferences loadPass = getSharedPreferences(allpass, MODE_PRIVATE);
    String empStrng = String.valueOf(getemn);
    String passes = "pass";
    if (getemn < 13) {
        passes = "pass" + empStrng;
        g.setData4(getemn, loadPass.getString(passes, "0123"));
    }
    String[] pass = g.getData4();
    if (i == 0 && getemp.equals(pass[getemn])) {
    g.setData3(getemn);
    Logscript();
    }
    if (i == 0 && !(getemp.equals(pass[getemn]))) {
        tfone.setText("No matches found");
        tftwo.setText("Enter password");
        edit2.setText("");
        i = 1;
    }
}
}
```

can anyone tell me where I went wrong here or how to actually check if someone entered a number?

Comment: Is edit the edittext itself or the string from the edittexts. How is it different from edit2

Comment: @akyirem samuel edit is a numeric text field only and defined as such in the related xml file, edit2 is a text field for entering a password and is defined as accepting text in the related xml file

Comment: Ok. I guess you have now realized the error. You should call the equals("") on the text entered in the edittext rather but not the edittext itself. Something like edit.getText().toString.equals(""). Hope that helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
if(!edit.getText().toString().equals(""))
```

Comment: Thanks that did the trick, I'm fairly new to java and have realized again and again java is all about everything equaling everything and repeating that fact over and over and over again, I would think that if(!edit.equals("")) would do the same thing but nope haha I was totally wrong. thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

```
if (!edit.equals(""))
```

This is the line probably you should be changing to:

```
if(!edit.getText().toString().equals(""))
```

Right now you are checking if the actual object of edit equals the blank number, not the text of the edit box.

If you are setting the integer to 0 by default, you could do something like this:

```
getemn = Integer.parseInt(edit.getText().toString().equals("") ? "0" : edit.getText.toString() );
```

Comment: ahhh ok I see what you're saying I will try that now

Comment: I meant to say, and i just edited my question, if you don't enter anything in the text field, which is a numeric text field and only brings up the number keyboard on your device, so you cant enter text at all just numbers

Comment: try using the `toString()` method when comparing the text to "".

Comment: well, this should've worked, please check and update where exactly are you getting the error i.e, on which line.

Comment: yes, adding the toString() worked, I'm having a tough time with why if (edit != null) {//code block} didn't work tho, null, as I currently understand it means there is nothing there, unless that only checks for the actual text or number field existing at all?

Comment: @Wraithious when you say `if(edit != null)`, you are checking the reference of edit to make sure that edit is initialized and has a reference to values. You are not checking if the edit contains text in the checkbox with that statement.

Answer (score 1):

Add this property to EditText in XML file

```
android:inputType="number"
```

And in Java :

```
if(!editText.getText().toString()isEmpty()){

//Your content here

}
```

Comment: yes, the first part of your answer android:inputType="number" I had set up that way from the beginning in the xml, The second part of your answer as @Drv and you have said solved my problem thank you very much

Comment: I am glad it helped you!! happy coding